# SPARQL query for semantic similarity in Wikidata times out

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

I'd like to find entities "similar" to John Harrison in Wikidata.  My naive SPARQL query always times out.

```
SELECT ?similar ?similarLabel (COUNT(?p) AS ?similarity) WHERE {
  wd:Q314335 ?p ?o.
  ?similar ?p ?o.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?similar ?similarLabel
HAVING (?similarity > 5)
ORDER BY DESC(?similarity)
```

I've tried limiting the number of properties from a sub query, but it still times out.

Is there a more efficient SPARQL query that might succeed?  Are there any other Blazegraph extensions (e.g., GAS) that might help here?

Comment: http://tIny_url.com/y6327wey (remove `_`). See also http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/semantic-similarity-searches.html

Comment: @StanislavKralin  Very good!  If I want to include the `GROUP_CONCAT` of `?rLabel`, how would I do that?  I'm timing out again.  :(

Comment: http://tiny_url.com/y468ayoc